# .ajax() JSONP Unterminated Regular Expression Literal

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a simple script that has a jQuery `.ajax()` that expects an HTML snippet as the returned data. Since it is a cross-domain call, I had to set `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

The expected returned data looks like:

```
<li><a href="https://sugarsync.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/293/">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://sugarsync.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/307">Link 2</a></li>
...
```

Unfortunately, when I ran the script, I got the following error (in the Firebug Console tab). I tried a different `dataType` such as `jsonp html` and `jsonp text html` but to no avail.

```
unterminated regular expression literal
...
```

This is the [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/hSefD/). Help, please?

Comment: `http://blog.sugarsync.com/blog/rn-android/` serves HTML, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the server set up to handle jsonp requests? If not then it won't work (from what I understand).

As an alternative there's a neat little jQuery plugin which will allow you to make cross-domain GET requests: https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

You can then just use `$.ajax` as you normally would:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://blog.sugarsync.com/blog/rn-android/',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#list').html(data.responseText);
      }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the html returned from the ajax web service in a json object. 
e.g. `{"html":"<li>the rest of your html</li>"}`

Then you'll have to unpack the json in the success function by using `$('#list').html(data.html)`

I think your data must be in a valid json format when using jsonp.